# Get the data repeated n number of times

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

Below is my data.

```
ID  Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
1   101     1000    0      10000
1   102     0       1000   10000

2   101     1000    0      10000
2   102     0       1000   10000

3   103     2000    0      500
3   104     0      250     500

4   101     1000    0      10000
4   102     0      1000    10000
4   103     500     0      10000
```

I am unable to get the id's which has same data and occurred 2 times.

According to the above data,expected id's are 1,2. Which are participated in the duplication of 2 times.
Please help.

Comment: Why did you cross out id #4 in your edit? It also has a row with the same values as ID #1,2.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct id
  from tbl x
  join (select col1,
               col2,
               col3,
               col4
          from tbl
         group by col1,
                  col2,
                  col3,
                  col4
        having count(distinct id) > 1) y
    on x.col1 = y.col1
   and x.col2 = y.col2
   and x.col3 = y.col3
   and x.col4 = y.col4
```

**Fiddle:** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8bce9/3/0

Your comments seem to suggest you want IDs that have rows that are identical in columns 1, 2, 3, and 4, on ALL rows, not just some rows. However, if that's the case, ID #s 1 and 2 are not even a match. Regardless, if that really is what you want -- perhaps it is, I don't know -- this should do that. It returns no results for your sample data above because, like I said, the 2nd row for ID # 1 does not match the 2nd row for ID # 2.

```
select id
  from tbl t
 where exists (select 1
          from tbl x
         where x.col1 = t.col1
           and x.col2 = t.col2
           and x.col3 = t.col3
           and x.col4 = t.col4
           and x.id <> t.id
           and not exists (select 1
                  from tbl z
                 where z.id = x.id
                   and z.col1 <> x.col1
                    or z.col2 <> x.col2
                    or z.col3 <> x.col3
                    or z.col4 <> x.col4));
```

Comment: Expected id's 1 and 2 only those are only like mirror images

Comment: ID #4 has exactly the same values for all columns 1, 2, 3, and 4. Why is that not also a "mirror image"?

Comment: As id#4 has other row, which is not identical with ID 1 and 2 because of 3 rd row.so id #4 will not come.If you see id#1 and #2 those are like xerox

Comment: Under that logic 1 and 2 wouldn't even be a match because they have rows that are not a match. They share values in col1/2/3/4 on one row, but not on their other row, so under your definition of "mirror image" they also do not meet that criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Try below sql

```
select ID from
(
select ID,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4, count(*) from table
       Group by ID,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
       Having count(*) > 1
) as UniqueData
```

Answer (score 0):

**General idea**

- For each ID build a long string by concatenating all values from all columns **and rows of that ID** together.
- IDs that have the same data will have the same concatenated string.
- Group by this string to find those IDs that have the same data.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c62b00/14/0)

```
WITH
CTE_Groups
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ID
    FROM tbl
)
,CTE_GroupsAggregated
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_Groups.ID
        ,CA_Data.XML_Value AS DataValues
    FROM
        CTE_Groups
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT 
              CAST(Col1 AS varchar(10))+','+
              CAST(Col2 AS varchar(10))+','+
              CAST(Col3 AS varchar(10))+','+
              CAST(Col4 AS varchar(10))+','
            FROM tbl
            WHERE tbl.ID = CTE_Groups.ID
            ORDER BY Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ) AS CA_XML(XML_Value)
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT CA_XML.XML_Value.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ) AS CA_Data(XML_Value)
)
,CTE_Duplicates
AS
(
  SELECT DataValues
  FROM CTE_GroupsAggregated
  GROUP BY DataValues
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT
  CTE_GroupsAggregated.ID
FROM
  CTE_GroupsAggregated
  INNER JOIN CTE_Duplicates ON CTE_Duplicates.DataValues = CTE_GroupsAggregated.DataValues
;
```

**result set**

```
ID
1
2
```

To understand better how it works include `DataValues` into the output and examine intermediate results of each CTE.